# The tolerance of using `==` to compare floating numbers in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I am now implementing a function that requires the input list `lst` to be a distribution, which means `sum(lst)` is equal to 1.

In the code, I use `assert` statement

```py
assert sum(lst) == 1, "the lst has to be a distribution"
```

However, as elements in `lst` will all be floating numbers, I am not sure whether `sum(lst) == 1` will be violated for some subtle cases because of machine precision. To be more specific, I guess my question is

- How `==` is implemented in the very low level. What is the tolerance for comparing two floating numbers? Does this value vary machine from machine (for example, the set of values returned by `sys.float_info`)?
- When is the good practice of using `==`. Besides comparing two floating numbers, are there other similar cases that warrant extra attention (for example, comparing strings, objects, etc).

Comment: When comparing a sum of a bunch of numbers, I'd recommend using alternatives to floats, like Decimal, since that'd have no rounding issues at all, and you don't have to re-invent the wheel. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) for some good alternatives. It also recommends the function `math.isclose` to compare floats within a certain specified tolerance.

Comment: or math.fsum(lst) on IEEE-754 algorithm